# How do I resolve this query?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I receive runtime error 3122 :

You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression `count(*)*t2.Daily_Charge_HKD` as part of the aggregate function

What I want to do in the query:

I want to group all the record in Opt_In_Customer_Record by event_plan_code, and have a total count for each of the code, then I reference the daily_charge from the daily_charge table by t1.event_plan_code = t2.event_plan_code, and multiply the daily_charge with the total count for each of the code

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnGenDaily_Click()
    Dim filename As String
    Dim prefix As String
    Dim qryDef As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database

    Set dbs = OpenDatabase(CurrentDb.Name)

    If IsNull(txtInputPath.value) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid input file location."
    Else
        If FileExists(txtInputPath.value) Then
            If IsNull(txtOutputPath3.value) Then
                MsgBox "Please enter a valid output file location."
            Else
                prefix = GetFileNamePrefix(txtInputPath.value)

                sql = "select t1.event_plan_code, count(*), count(*)*t2.Daily_Charge_HKD " & _
                      "from Opt_In_Customer_Record t1 Inner Join Daily_Charge t2 " & _
                      "On (t1.event_plan_code=t2.event_plan_code and t2.Home_BMO='" & prefix & "') " & _
                      "group by t1.event_plan_code " & _
                      "order by t1.event_plan_code "

                MsgBox sql

                If ObjectExists("Query", "getDailyCharge") Then
                     DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "getDailyCharge"
                End If

                With dbs
                    .QueryTimeout = 0
                    Set QueryDef = .CreateQueryDef("getDailyCharge", sql)
                End With

                strPathToSave = txtOutputPath3.value

                DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "getDailyCharge", strPathToSave, True
                MsgBox "Daily charge report generated."
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Input file does not exist. Please enter again."
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Could it be because you are not grouping by `t2.Daily_Charge_HKD` ?

Comment: Yes, but here I don't want to group by that. This make a different group.

Comment: If it's not a grouping field, you cannot use the field directly in select; the field can only be used in a summarizing function like sum, avg, min, max, etc..

Answer (score 0):

I know you mentioned in a comment that you don't want to group by "t2.Daily_Charge_HK", but to use that in the way you are doing with access you will need to group it, because of your join I'm guessing you only have one Daily Charge value for each event plan code so the grouping in this case won't be a problem. e.g. all event plan codes with id of 1 and Home BMO a prefix of x will have the same charge rate.

Change:

```
sql = "select t1.event_plan_code, count(*), count(*)*t2.Daily_Charge_HKD " & _
    "from Opt_In_Customer_Record t1 Inner Join Daily_Charge t2 " & _
    "On (t1.event_plan_code=t2.event_plan_code and t2.Home_BMO='" & prefix & "') " & _
    "group by t1.event_plan_code " & _
    "order by t1.event_plan_code "
```

Into:

```
sql = "select t1.event_plan_code, count(*), count(*)*t2.Daily_Charge_HKD " & _
    "from Opt_In_Customer_Record t1 Inner Join Daily_Charge t2 " & _
    "On (t1.event_plan_code=t2.event_plan_code and t2.Home_BMO='" & prefix & "') " & _
    "group by t1.event_plan_code, t2.Daily_Charge_HKD " & _
    "order by t1.event_plan_code, t2.Daily_Charge_HKD "
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Finally I come up with this solution and it works:

sql = "select t1.event_plan_code, Count, Count*Daily_Charge_HKD As 'Count * Daily_Charge_HKD' " & _

```
  "from (select event_plan_code, count(*) As Count " & _
  "from Opt_In_Customer_Record " & _
  "group by event_plan_code " & _
  "order by event_plan_code) t1, Daily_Charge t2 " & _
  "where t1.event_plan_code=t2.event_plan_code and t2.Home_BMO='" & prefix & "' " & _
  "order by t1.event_plan_code"
```